# PHP - how to call a function that is part of an object where one part is a variable?

Tags: php, method-call

I need to call an function that is part of an object.  The following call works as one would expect:

```
$someobject = getobject();
$result = $someobject->somefunction->value();
```

However, I need the "somefunction" component to be a variable.

I have tried to do it like this:

```
$var = 'somefunction';
$result = '$someobject->' . $var '->value'();
```

This does *not* work, but I hope it conveys what I am looking for.  I've also tried a lot of variations based upon `call_user_func()` – without finding a syntax that works.

I am running: PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.3. Vanilla version for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Does this work? ```$result = $someobject->{$var}(); $result = $result.value();```

Comment: in your question `$someobject->somefunction->value();` value is a function. But somefunction is not

Comment: @SwetankPoddar No: ParseError: syntax error, unexpected 'var' (T_VAR) in ...

Comment: Which PHP version are you running?

Comment: @SwetankPoddar `$result = $result.value();` is not a PHP code

Comment: @splash58 oops, my bad :P Python habits. thanks.

Comment: @splash58 Well, it is valid PHP, it just doesn’t mean what you want it to probably.

Comment: @deceze i don't think he want concatenation here

Comment: Maybe you mean this `$result = $someobject->${var}->value();`

Comment: Oh wait, var is reserved keyword in PHP. Try changing the the name of "var" variable to something else and try again.

Comment: @SwetankPoddar It is, but `->${foo}` is the wrong syntax anyway; that will interpret `foo` as a constant, try to use that constant's value as a variable name, and then that variable's value as the property (or method) name! You were thinking of `->{$foo}`, but the braces are actually unnecessary in simple cases like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a property or method dynamically based on its name, you simply use one more `$` sign than you would normally.

For example, if we have this object:

```php
class Foo {
    public $someproperty = 'Hello!';

    public function somefunction() {
        return 'Hello World';
    }
}

$someobject = new Foo;
```

Then we can access the property normally:

```php
echo $someobject->someproperty;
```

Or dynamically by name:

```php
$var = 'someproperty';
echo $someobject->$var;
```

Similarly, we can access the method normally:

```php
echo $someobject->somefunction();
```

Or dynamically by name:

```php
$var = 'somefunction';
$result = $someobject->$var();
```

Note that your example is a bit confusing, because you talk about "accessing a function where one part is a variable", but all you're actually trying to do is access a *property* dynamically, and you then happen to be calling a method on the object stored in that property. So the part you've called `somefunction` is actually the name of a property.

Here's an example that looks a bit like yours, but with the names changed:

```php
class A {
    public $foo;
}
class B {
    public function value() {
        return 'Hello World';
    }
}

$a = new A;
$a->foo = new B;

$propertyname = 'foo';

echo $a->$propertyname->value();
```

Comment: Accepted. Very good explanation. I agree that my framing of the question is confusing. I am *not* a PHP wizard, so this is is due to my inexperiebce.  Feel free to edit the question to clean up the terminology.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Blueprint 
{
    public function method() 
    {
        return 'placeholder';   
    }
}

$object = new Blueprint;
$method = 'method';

// this will output `placeholder`
echo $object->{$method}();
```

Comment: Please provide some context to your answer, rather than just providing code.

Answer (score 0):

Hooray!

The following (two alternative valid syntaxes are produced for the second line) works as expected without producing any errors:

```
$foobar = 'somefunction';
$result = $someobject->$foobar->value();
$result = $someobject->{$foobar}->value();
```

The following:

```
$foobar = 'somefunction';
$result = $someobject->${foobar}->value();
```

also works (i.e. it produces the expected result), but it also produces this warning:

> Warning: Use of undefined constant foobar - assumed 'foobar' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) …

Many thanks to all that commented.  In particular *Duc Nguyen* and *Swetank Poddar*.  I think it was the comment by *Duc Nguyen* in combination with the following comment by *Swetank Poddar* that finally cracked it.